# Как лучше обрабатывать ajax запросы на php?

Tags: php, javascript

Как рациональнее обрабатывать ajax запросы на php, если учитывать, что таких запросов очень много разных на любой вкус? Для каждого запроса иметь на сервере свой php-файл-обработчик? Или в запросах передавать тип запроса и потом в одном жирном php-диспетчере раскуривать этот тип? Как это делается? Наверняка многие решали этот вопрос. Наверняка существуют "best practices" и/или design patterns. Товарищи php-шники, поделитесь опытом.
PHP-фреймворки не предлагать. Хочется ручками поковырять.

Спасибо

Comment: Я, например, использую один PHP-Файл обработчик запросов, и все AJAX-запросы передаю именно ему. В нем же очень много разного кода, который разбит на switch->case для POST и GET-запросов.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд вариантов тут не много. Ну, класс создайте, который будет обрабатывать запросы. Так или иначе, но вы принимаете параметр (толи GET, толи POST) и в зависимости от ключа, выполняете то или иное действие. К тому же, не всегда надо создавать однотипные ответы по запросу.

Answer (score 2):

У вас должен быть контроллер, который подготавливает данные, а дальше просто накладывается соответвующая вьюха в зависимости от того в каком формате нужны данные.

Пример на псевдо-коде:

```
$data = <получаем данные для шаблона>    
if (isAjax){
    $response = getAjax($data)
}else {
    $response =getHtml($data);
}
echo  $response;//отдаем браузеру или как оно у вас организовано
```